# Ember with Node (MEEN stack?)

Tags: node.js, ember.js, express, mongoose

I've been building apps on the Rails platform for over a year now. That being said, if you can make any comparisons to the Rails equivalent, it might help all parties involved. Just a thought.

Anyway, I'm trying to wrap my head around node, and the front end framework, ember. I was originally intrigued by stumbling across the [MEAN stack](http://mean.io/). After digging into that a bit, I realized I didn't really like angular all that much, and started looking up alternates. Ember seems pretty awesome, and the syntax seems much cleaner without all of the `ng-` markup to the DOM. I'd like to experiment with mongoDB, and I feel like this approach will teach me a lot.

My question, I guess, is Express. What is the role of Express when using Node? It seems that Ember (even Angular, for that matter) has a pretty expressive router. In my limited understanding of it all, I thought Express was for routes? I found [this](https://github.com/timfpark/messages), which seems to be a MEEN stack of sorts.

The package.json for MEAN is massive, but that MEEN I linked to, is very tiny, with just express, mongoose, and request. Another question, I suppose, is what are the different roles in a MEAN / MEEN stack? Does that make sense? I'm rambling a bit, lol, but I'm hoping to keep researching and playing with this stuff until I have that 'Ah ha!' moment, you know?

mongoose - seems to be a better way of interacting with mongoDB?

express - routes specific to node?

request - seems simple enough. send external requests to other pages on the web. I can't see what the equivalent package would be in MEAN, is this truly needed?

grunt - runs a bunch of stuff so that all the different parts play nicely together?

Any explanations, links, or help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Express is middleware for node, essentially, it makes working with node a boatload easier (defining routes, plugins, etc). Mongoose (like you said) helps interactions with Mongo. IMO, Mongo itself isn't very hard to work with, I generally prefer no plugins for that.

Comment: I'm used to a database being 'in' the app. With rails, it was in the db folder, and I could open it up and look at it with a SQL viewer. Any insight on how to point mongo to a location within my app, and how to 'look' at the data?

Comment: Well the MongoDB will be connected to via a connection string (typical stuff) -- as for looking at the data, I use RoboMongo. Nice GUI and pretty easy to work with. Most of the time however you can just get away with connecting through a terminal and running shell commands from there.

Comment: K... I'm looking through the folders that http://mean.io set up for me, here... where is the connection string? I have to fire up `mongod` first, then `grunt` to get the server running. Any idea where the call to the DB is?

Comment: That's using Mongoose, checkout app/models/user.js

Comment: alright, that clears up mongoose a little bit. I also checked `server.js` and there is `//Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);`. I searched for files and text, and couldn't come up with any reference to `config.db`. Is it writing to the default location? `c:/data/db`?

Comment: checking out robomongo... looking in `c:/data/db`... which file/files contain the actual data? I tried dragging everything in there, lol

Comment: With Rails, you were using SQLite, which uses a single file as a database.  In produdction, you would set up Rails with MySQL or some other database software.

MySQL and Mongo are database applications, which is what most databases are. They are software that you run and connect to to retrieve information, not files that you can open in an application.

With Mongo, you start the application with the mongod command and in a separate CLI you access it with the mongo command.

Test mongo here, to better understand: http://try.mongodb.org/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're coming from Rails I'd break it down like this:

**node.js** -> Ruby - your server side language / platform

**express** -> Rails - your server side framework, although a little more like Sinatra

**grunt** -> Rake - your preprocessor / build tool

**npm** -> gem - your *server side* package manager

**Angular.js** / **Ember.js** -> No direct map, your *client side* framework.

**mongoose.js** -> ActiveRecord, but for MongoDb. If you want a SQL ORM use *Sequelize*

Two other tools worth learning are

**bower** -> your *client side* package manager, for things like bootstrap

**yeoman** -> all round js app scaffolding, ties everything together, a great tool to see how to scaffold "best practice" apps.

Comment: I had not made that connection to mongoose... nice. I'm picking it up in pieces, now. I have a rails app with mongoid, just to help me wrap my head around document storage. I've been tinkering with angular, and that's starting to make a bit more sense as well. Thanks, though! This really clears up some stuff.

Comment: I love answers like this; makes transitions so much easier :)